# Is it possible to clone a repo from GitHub without an account?

Tags: ssh, git, github, repository

I'm hosting my company's interview project on Github. We will have candidates clone the repo and work with it on their local machine during the interview itself. They never have to push code to the repo.

I have the code in a Github repo but the repo is private, because I do not want people being able to search the internet for "Company X Interview" and have this repo come up. We will send the candidates a URL to clone the repo immediately before the actual interview.

The problem I'm having is that this seems to require a GitHub account. I would hope most of my candidates coming in for an interview are on GitHub but I don't want it to be a requirement.

Is there some way I can configure this repo's security settings such that it is still a private repo but can be cloned by anyone who has the URL (without needing an account)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to accomplish this:

- Authenticating with SSH
  This is described in the article
  [Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)
  but is more complicated to setup.
- Using HTTPS and providing your username and password in the URL.
  Example for a private repository:

  ```
    git clone https://user:password@github.com/user/project.git
  ```

  If you use 2FA to secure your GitHub account then you’ll need to use
  a personal access token instead of a password, as explained in the article
  [Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: So in the first scenario the candidate would have to provide their public SSH key to use before the interview, right? And in the second scenario they would still have to have an account. Or I suppose we could setup some sort of dummy account with access and provide them the URL with the dummy account credentials already baked in. I don't think either solution is really what I was hoping for, but thanks.

Comment: The second method requires you giving away *your* user-name & password.

Comment: right, yeah that's why I was thinking we could create a dummy account. Seems kinda hacky, but could work